# Why does file_put_contents perform poorly in this benchmark?

Tags: php, text-files, benchmarking

I have created simple benchmark for part of my code which I was concerned was not working properly. I have came up with very odd results. Take a look at this benchmark:
[benchmark](http://dharman.eu/test/test6.php)
[test file](http://dharman.eu/test/test.txt)

The benchmark code is:

```
$start = microtime(true)*1000;

//code
$log=file_get_contents('test.txt').'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'."\n";
file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX);

$end=microtime(true)*1000;
$time = $end-$start;
echo 'Time : '.(int)$time.'ms<br />';


$start = microtime(true)*1000;

//code
$log='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'."\n";
file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX|FILE_APPEND);

$end=microtime(true)*1000;
$time = $end-$start;
echo 'Time : '.(int)$time.'ms<br />';
```

What I have noticed is that the append option which in my opinion should be faster is actually slower. If the problem is with my benchmark then please tell me.
Can anyone explain me why it might be slower?

Additionally I have found that when you hold F5(refresh continously) the text file gets cleared up(:O) Why?

**EDIT**
I have changed the benchmark to do it in 100 iterations now as Ilya Bursov said. The append operation now seems to take negligable amount of time to finish while the read and write takes forever as it should be. However a single iteration still produces weird results even when clearing cache. I know that could be influenced by many things even margin of error but a thourough answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What does cleared up mean?

Comment: The file becomes empty.

Comment: Well it doesn't look like anyone has answered you.  I don't know the answer to your question but the only thing that I can see accounting for the difference is that the long script has to set the pointer to the end of the file before starting to write.

Comment: Losing the file is probably just because the opening/closing/saving overlapped and caused an conflict.  Not sure if you could find it in an error log.  Basically I wouldn't count a using a text file to store data that is going to be written to at a fast rate.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "weird results" when doing a single iteration. I used the exact same code you've posted, with test.txt being a 50MB file seeded with /dev/urandom. read+concat+write runs in about 500ms, append-mode file_put_contents in about 50ms. The only thing I can think of is that, on your system, perhaps the buffer is still flushing to the file when the append only file_put_contents is started, so it would have to wait until the previous file_put_contents is actually done with the write. (You're not keeping that in mind in your benchmark, btw)

Comment: @ilias could you elaborate more on how does the buffer work in PHP. Does it work in background and the next operation has to wait for it to finish? How avoid this in my benchmark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you're measuring wrong items with wrong methods in wrong environment

1. for first result you're measuring read + write of big data
2. for second result you're measuring variable init + append of small data
3. you're doing only 1 iteration, which gives very unstable results in multi-threaded environment
4. you're calling script via apache, to do benchmark it is better to call it from command line
5. different settings for disk/system cache buffers can really change results

Here are my guess why times are so different:

As you have only 1 iteration of process you can have next situation:

1. Read file (it is in cache) - we can consider 0 time here
2. concat file with const - almost 0 time
3. Write data into ouput buffer - not to the disk, but to memory buffer, which will be flushed later - almost 0 time
4. now you're re-initing variable - I hope 0 time, or it can be bigger as you're reusing variable it probably php re-arranges something in memory
5. you're writing to file, BUT you have to wait until buffers from p3 are actually flushed

You can try to change your code a little bit:

```
$start = microtime(true)*1000;
$log=file_get_contents('test.txt').'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'."\n";
file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX);
clearstatcache(); // NOTE call here
$end=microtime(true)*1000;
$time = $end-$start;
echo 'Time : '.(int)$time.'ms<br />';
$start = microtime(true)*1000;
$log='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'."\n";
file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX|FILE_APPEND);
clearstatcache(); // NOTE another call here
$end=microtime(true)*1000;
$time = $end-$start;
echo 'Time : '.(int)$time.'ms<br />';
```

and now you're getting different results

**So**

time 1 in your test: read and write from cache

time 2 is actual write to disk and maybe some overhead for memory operations

Consider following code:

```
$appendString = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$log=file_get_contents('test.txt').$appendString."\n";
$iterations = 1000;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$iterations; $i++)
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX);
$end=microtime(true);

$time = ($end*1000 - $start*1000) / $iterations;
echo 'Time : '.$time.'ms'. "\n";

$log=$appendString."\n";

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<$iterations; $i++)
    file_put_contents('test.txt', $log, LOCK_EX|FILE_APPEND);
$end=microtime(true);

$time = ($end*1000 - $start * 1000) / $iterations;
echo 'Time : '.$time.'ms' . "\n";
```

on windows:

```
Time : 0.22101293945313ms
Time : 0.039001953125ms

PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Aug 20 2013 16:45:40)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

on linux:

```
Time : 7.6823303222656ms
Time : 0.008222900390625ms

PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u4 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 14:37:41)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

these numbers looks reasonable, even if there are 2 different systems, as in first loop we have to write big string and in second loop only small part appending to it, and we're using iterations to calculate avg result

conclusion: as it was expected - appending to file works faster than rewriting whole file, at least because of much smaller amount of disk IO needed

Comment: The answer is very good but not sufficient. You are only comparing the write operation not the whole append operation. The issue here is which one is faster and better to use. You are right about benchmarking in CLI but this will not give you real life results. Users will access the site via apache and thats what I am concerned about.

Comment: @Dharman what do you mean by "whole append" and "write"? First test measures re-writing of whole file, second only append to this file. Users of course will use apache, and you will need to emulate simultaneous access, but it should be done not via browser and refresh

Comment: to append you need to read, concat and write. You start the timer after you read and concat.

Comment: And yes I know this will make the first approach even slower. Just add a conclusion to your answer suming up what you have found and which approach is better to use.

Answer (score 4):

Php `fopen` calls the `open` system call with `O_TRUNC` which means it truncates the file before write in non-append mode. This truncation takes time, and makes it slower.

After the truncate happened and before the real content arrived you see the empty file.

You can verify this with `strace` in command line.

Comment: The file does not seem to be empty, it is empty. I suppose it is caused by the deadlock on the file.

Comment: I mean the the writer process sent the data to the file, but while the file is not closed, other processes can't read this data because the data resides only in the write buffers/caches.